# Entity Framework - supply a connection string to constructor

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF in my C# project. We're about to add clients which will have other databases with other connection strings.
There's no need to sync between DBs.
I tried using the following c'tor (the 2nd out of 3 supplied):

```
 public AppEntities(string connectionString)
```

and I get the following error: 'Keyword not supported: 'data source'.'
The connection string is as follows:

```
metadata=res://EntityFramework/App.csdl|res://EntityFramework/App.ssdl|res://EntityFramework/App.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=dbname\dbname;Initial Catalog=App;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=User;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;
```

This is the same connection string that is used when taken from App.Config. I don't want to take it from there but rather build it myself (thus leaving the username & password hard-coded in my app's code and not in free text.
Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connectionstring parameter is not an [Entity Framework Connectionstring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx) (as in the .config file) but it has to be a "normal" .net connectionstring.

The link's example shows how to "convert" the ef connectionstring to a normal connectionstring (using the **EntityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString()** method). If you pass the app.config's unprepared string you will get the mentioned error.

You can use the [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) to parse the app.config value and convert it.

Hope that helps.